# Plugin migrations for Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, migration, redmine

I'm developing a plugin for Redmine.
How do I create a migration for it?

If I use script/generate plugin_migration, it'll be placed in /db/migrate folder, but I need it to be in my plugin's folder.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating migration manually, but maybe there is a more common way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `script/generate migration` to create the migration and then move it into the plugin directory.  When you move it, make sure to change from the timestamped format (20090719...) to the integer format (001_...)

I tend to just create the migrations by hand myself since they are pretty basic.

Eric Davis

Comment: Just a note, on newer versions of redmine and rails, the command looks like:
bundle exec ruby script/rails generate migration

Answer (score 0):

The way most plugins do it (thinking of restful_authentication and others) is to have a generator that needs to be run when you install the plugin.  This would generate the migration and put it in db/migrate where it then becomes part of your project migrations.  I can't really think of a better way to do this.  Using something like [desert](http://pivotallabs.com/users/brian/blog/articles/459-build-your-own-rails-plugin-platform-with-desert) can help, but adds its own bit of overhead as well.