# Plugin migrations for Redmine: place plugin in db/migrate instead of plugin folder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm a newbie in ruby on rails and creating a redmine plugin. I created a model `Allissue` without using any column. Now I wanted to add a column `project_name` with the help of migration `./script/generate migration AddRoleToAllissue project_name:string`.

But it places migration in folder `db/migrate` named `20120722192815_add_role_to_allissue.rb` instead of plugin migrate folder. I followed [stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221154/plugin-migrations-for-redmine) and move migrated file to plugin folder `mv ./db/migrate/20120722192815_add_role_to_allissue.rb ./vendor/plugins/redmine_allissues/db/migrate/002_add_role_to_allissue.rb`.

I just wanted to know alternative for plugin migration in which no need of moving migrated file to plugin folder. I'm not sure but there may be a command for plugin migration. Thanks

Comment: Try running the generator from within the plugin directory.

Comment: @mosch : i did same........BUt still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you are generating a Rails migration and not a Redmine plugin migration. This is why your migration file is in `db/migrate` folder.

The right syntax is for Rails 3.x (Redmine >= 2.x):

```
 rails generate redmine_plugin_model <plugin_name> <model_name> ...
```

for Rails 2.x (Redmine <2.x):

```
 script/generate redmine_plugin_model <plugin_name> <model_name> ...
```

It will generate the migration in the right place.

You should check the tutorials on the Redmine wiki about [plugins](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins).