# how to replace null by value of an attribute in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine-plugins, rails-console

I'm writing a redmine plugin where model is `Allissue`. I added two attributes `project_name` and `create_date`. First, I added column `project_name` and assigned them some values. Second, I added one more column `created_date` for which values become null as shown in figure. [image]

I want to replace null with integer values. It is very basic question but I don't know as I'm a newbie. Can you suggest me the syntax to add values. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to happen automatically, add something like this to your model:

```
class Allissue
  ...
  before_save do |a|
    a.create_date = Time.now # or whatever you want it to be
  end
  ...
end
```

or manually, you would do (for all multiple objects):

```
Allissue.all.each{|a| a.create_date = Time.now; a.save}
```

or (for a single object):

```
a = Allissue.find(1)
a.create_date = Time.now
a.save
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks...but create_date is not a Magic columns so I can't relate it with Time.now. It depends on project perspective.

Comment: Can u answer my another [question]:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607405/plugin-migrations-for-redmine-place-plugin-in-db-migrate-instead-of-plugin-fold)